# Create trapezoid using d3 svg.area

Tags: d3.js, svg

I’m breaking my head with `D3` for creating a `trapezoid` using `SVG.Area`.
Can someone tell me whether it’s possible to achieve this if yes please brief me,as I can see only 3 assessors `x,y1 and y0`.I’m not sure how I can fix different `x` value

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `d3.svg.area`, you should be using [svg:polygon](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#svg_polygon) or `d3.svg.line` combined with a [closepath](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataClosePathCommand) command to draw trapezoids.

Here's a quick example of how I'd do it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500);
      
    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
    var points = [{
        x: 100, y: 100
      },{
        x: 400, y: 100
      },{
        x: 375, y: 150
      },{
        x: 125, y: 150
      }];
      
    svg.append('path')
      .attr("d", line(points) + 'Z')
      .style("fill", "orange")
      .style("stroke", "black");
        
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now, you must use `d3.line()`